# Worklight 6.1 -How to get requested environment in worklight adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have four environment in worklight project which are `Android`, `Iphone`, `Ipad` and `Windows`. My doubt is how to get which environment is requesting on adapter when hitting from client.

For example if i am hitting adapter from `iPhone` then how will i come to know request is coming from `iPhone` so that i can get it on adapter side and log it in api request.

Comment: To clarify, you have 4 "environments" (not "projects") in your worklight project, 1 adapter. You want to know, from the adapter, which environment the client is using?

Comment: yes exactly single project with four enviornment and sigle adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in feature to get the current environment from an adapter, however you can still find out that information by other ways. For example:

- Parse the User-Agent from the HTTP header

> ```
> var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
> var userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
> ```

Then search for keywords such as "android", etc.

- Or, easier in my opinion, send the environment name as a parameter to your invokeProcedure!

> WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
>   adapter : 'sample',
>   procedure : 'sample',
>   parameters : [env: WL.Client.getEnvironment()],
>   });